# Jquery 400 - Autocomplete Spring MVC Not Working

Tags: jquery, ajax, spring-mvc, jquery-ui, jquery-ui-autocomplete

I am facing a problem with Autocomplete Jquery. I have spent the whole day trying various different examples and keep ending up on the same error.

***What am I trying to achieve?***

Get a drop down list of my subcategories as the user types in the search bar from my database using the Spring MVC pattern.

***What error am I facing?***
[image]

***What have I tried to solve this problem?***

After reading various topics on this particular problem on stackoverflow and various other sites. I found out that this is usually a problem because scripts are not in order. I have tried multiple combination of rearranging my scripts but still cannot solve this error.

***This is my header.***

```
<meta charset="utf-8">
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
<script src="resources/js/jquery-3.1.1.min.js"></script>
<script src="resources/js/angular.min.js"></script> 
<link href="resources/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<script src="resources/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>   
<script src="resources/js/dirPagination.js"></script>
<link href="resources/css/jquery-ui.theme.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<script src="resources/js/jquery-ui.min.js"></script>
<link id="sidebarcss" href="resources/css/simple-sidebar.css" rel="stylesheet">
<link href="resources/css/footer-distributed-with-address-and-phones.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<link href="resources/css/megamenu.css" rel="stylesheet" />  
<link href="resources/css/Main.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<link rel="icon" href="resources/images/logo.png">
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/font-awesome/4.7.0/css/font-awesome.min.css">
<title>MiniKart</title>
```

***This is my Script***

```
$(document).ready(function() {
$(function() {
$("#searchbar").autocomplete({
source: function(request, response) {
$.ajax({
url: "/MiniKart/getSubCategory",
type: "POST",
data: { subCategoryName: request.subCategoryName },
dataType: "json",

success: function(data) {
response($.map(data, function(v,i){
return {
label: v.subCategoryName,
value: v.subCategoryName
};
}));
}
});
}
});
});
});
```

***This is my Controller***

```
List<SubCategory> data = new ArrayList<SubCategory>();



@RequestMapping(value = "/getSubCategory", method = RequestMethod.POST, produces = "application/json")
 public @ResponseBody List<SubCategory> getSubCategory(@RequestParam String subCategoryName, HttpServletResponse response) {
 return simulateSearchResult(subCategoryName);

}


 private List<SubCategory> simulateSearchResult(String subCategoryName) {

 List<SubCategory> result = new ArrayList<SubCategory>();

 for (SubCategory subCategory : data) {
 if (subCategory.getSubCategoryName().contains(subCategoryName)) {
 result.add(subCategory);
 }
 }

return result;
 }
```

***The current example I am trying to follow***

[Spring MVC Autocomplete](https://javatutorials13.wordpress.com/2014/04/03/jquerys-autocomplete-functionality-in-a-spring-mvc-application/)

***Some Extra Info***

Jquery UI - 1.12.1

Eclipse - Neon

Maven Dependencies

```
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.codehaus.jackson</groupId>
        <artifactId>jackson-mapper-asl</artifactId>
        <version>1.9.13</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.codehaus.jackson</groupId>
        <artifactId>jackson-core-asl</artifactId>
        <version>1.9.13</version>
    </dependency>
```

**What am I doing wrong here?** All suggestions are welcome. Thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finally solved it after various different approaches...
Here is what I did

1. Used a Standalone version of autocomplete script.
2. Populated data with my category list.
3. Changed return type of getTags & simulateSearchResult to String.
4. Used Gson to convert result to Json-String and returned it.

***My Header***

```
<head>
<meta charset="utf-8">
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
<script src="resources/js/jquery-3.1.1.min.js"></script>
<script src="resources/js/angular.min.js"></script>
<script src="resources/js/jquery.autocomplete.min.js"></script> 
<link href="resources/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<script src="resources/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>   
<script src="resources/js/dirPagination.js"></script>


<link id="sidebarcss" href="resources/css/simple-sidebar.css" rel="stylesheet">
<link href="resources/css/footer-distributed-with-address-and-phones.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<link href="resources/css/megamenu.css" rel="stylesheet" />  
<link href="resources/css/Main.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<link rel="icon" href="resources/images/logo.png">
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/font-awesome/4.7.0/css/font-awesome.min.css">
<title>MiniKart</title>
```

***My Script***

```
$(document).ready(function() {

$('#searchbar').autocomplete({
    serviceUrl: '${pageContext.request.contextPath}/getTags',
    paramName: "categoryName",
    delimiter: ",",
   transformResult: function(response) {

    return {
      //must convert json to javascript object before process
      suggestions: $.map($.parseJSON(response), function(item) {

          return { value: item.categoryName, data: item.categoryId };
       })

     };

        }

 });

});
```

***My Controller***

```
@RequestMapping(value = "/getTags", method = RequestMethod.GET)
public @ResponseBody String getTags(@RequestParam String categoryName) {

    return simulateSearchResult(categoryName);

}

private String simulateSearchResult(String categoryName) {

    List<Category> result = new ArrayList<Category>();
    List<Category> data = categoryService.listCategory();
    Gson gson = new GsonBuilder().excludeFieldsWithoutExposeAnnotation().create();
    String j = null;
    // iterate a list and filter by tagName
    for(Category tag : data) {

        if (tag.getCategoryName().contains(categoryName)) {

            result.add(tag);
            j=gson.toJson(result);

        }
    }

    return j;
}
```

Comment: Gson i did not get dude